# Jasmine spy to fake ajax call to test callback results

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback, jasmine

I'm using Jasmine 2.0 and trying to test the results of a callback after an ajax call.  I've tried several things that I've found online, but have not found a solution to my problem.  I'm new to Jasmine and JQuery, and having a pretty tough time with this issue.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Here is sample code being tested:

```
//common.js
function getSomeServiceResponse(method, param, callback) {
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: "https://some.thing.com/api/mobile/" + method,
    data: param
})
    .done(function (data) {
        var response = $.parseJSON(data);

        //some stuff

        if ($.isFunction(callback)) {
            callback(response);
        }
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {

        //some error handling stuff 

        if ($.isFunction(callback)) {
            callback({
                ResultNumber: -1,
            });
        }
    });
}

//main.js
var someGlobalObj = {
    //some stuff for global obj 
    //some funcs

    querySession: function (callback) {

        //Some validation stuff

        getSomeServiceResponse(
            "querysomesession", {
                //some params
            },
            function (data) {                
                someGlobalObj.sessionData = data.Session;
                someGlobalObj.info = data.Info;

                if ($.isFunction(callback)) {
                    callback(data);
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

The test (feel free to comment about the test setup/layout as I am new to this and it may be incorrect):

```
describe("querySession()", function () {
    describe("with existing session found", function () {
        var response;

        beforeEach(function () {
            spyOn($, 'ajax').and.callFake(function (req) {
                var d = $.Deferred();
                var data = {
                    "Info": [],
                    "Session": {
                        "ID": 999,
                        "DateCreate": "\/Date(1398966244520)\/",
                        //Some other stuff
                    },
                    "ResultNumber": 0,
                };
                d.resolve(data);
                return d.promise();
            });

            someGlobalObj.sessionId = 1;

            someGlobalObj.querySession(function (data) {
                response = data;
            });
        });

        it("should set someGlobalObj.sessionData with an ID of 999", function () {
            //expect(someGlobalObj.sessionData.ID).toBe(999);
            expect(response.Session.ID).toBe(999);
        });
```

In short, someGlobalObj.querySession is called with a callback passed to it.  Within querySession, getSomeServiceResponse is called with a callback (calling original callback) passed to it.  After the callbacks fire, I'm expecting the data passed to populate my response to be what is set in someGlobalObj.  This is not my code, but I may be able to answer some questions if there are any.  Sorry for any confusion.

**Edit**
I'm now getting into the fake, as I've added some console logging.  The test fails with an error: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token o".  If I just do d.resolve('fake'), I get "Unexpected token k" instead.  Not sure where this error is coming from.

Comment: Anything on the console? I can only imagine to see the behavior you described if there is a syntax error or even an exception in your `spyOn` code

Comment: I'm not getting any errors in console.  I've updated the above.  I was n't getting passed the validation part that I removed from querySession(), which is now fixed by setting someGlobalObj.sessionId before calling querySession().  I get some strange syntax errors and the test fails.  "Unexpected token o/k"

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem to the unexpected token syntax error.

The culprit was:

```
var data = {
    "Info": [],
    "Session": {
        "ID": 999,
        "DateCreate": "\/Date(1398966244520)\/",
        //Some other stuff
    },
    "ResultNumber": 0,
};
```

In getSomeServiceResponse.done:

```
var response = $.parseJSON(data);
```

I changed data to a JSON to resolve the issue.  The original issue was that there was some validation that I didn't catch preventing getSomeServiceResponse to even be called, so the spy was never used.  This was obscure in my question, as I had removed the validation code.

Sorry for the waste of time...stumped by late coding again.